# How do I stop List Items from jumping when dragging in chrome?

Tags: jquery, html-lists, drag, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm using two UL's and scrolling them horizontally using javascript, but they jump about 10-20 px when the list items are dragged between the lists. This happens in chrome, but not in firefox. Problem is, it's fixed in chrome when setting the UL Li's to float:left, but that breaks the whole thing in firefox (the list does not stay on one line). Help!

Here's the web page, please open in webkit/chrome and firefox

http://www.senseculture.com/timeline_new.html

The Code I'm using for the draggable is:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
        $( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).sortable({
            connectWith: ".timeline_content"
        }).disableSelection();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like an issue where Chrome is treating default css properties differently than Firefox.  You can pass an option to `Selectable` to add a class to the `placeholder` - that allows you to easily style that `placeholder`:

```
$(function() {
        $( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).sortable({
            connectWith: ".timeline_content",
            placeholder: "timeline-placeholder"
        }).disableSelection();
    });
```

The following style (although a bit weird) worked for me:

```
.timeline-placeholder {
    display:  inline !important;
    padding:  0 99px;
    width:  2px;
}
```

I generally dislike the need to use `!important` / limit its use, but default behavior of the `placeholder` is to be set to `display: block` which needed to be overriden.

**edit**: I found one solution to your problem, but not the cause - would be interested to see if anyone knows what property or combination of properties is causing that.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I did end up using a placeholder, though I used different CSS values for the size, margin, and padding. Thanks!